# SSH key asking for passphrase on Unix but not Window

Tags: ssh, unix

I have this weird problem. I am using SSH key to connect to my-server. I have generated both public and private key without password and my public key is installed on my-server. I can connect to my-server from my local (Window 7) using private key but when I am trying to connect from a remote-server (Linux to Unix ) to my-server using the same key it is asking for password. I am using following command.

```
sftp -o "IdentityFile=<location-of-key>" user_id@server.name.com



 my-local: Window 7
 remote-server: Suse Linux 11 (x86_64)
 my-server: SunOS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you connect from Linux, you need to convert the private key from ppk format (understood by windows programs) to openssh format.

There is answer for this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/2196426).

You need to:

- Go to `Conversions->Export OpenSSH` and export your private key from PuttyGEN after loading your PRIVATE key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
sftp -i "<location-of-key>" user_id@server.name.com
```

From the man page:

> -i identity_file
>   Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.  This option is directly passed to ssh(1).

Comment: same error "Enter passphrase for key"

Comment: Can you use regular ssh?

Comment: yes, I can use regular ssh from my local but not from remote

Comment: Quick edit:
Removed the "IdentityFile=" part of the command

Comment: Can you post actual command?

Comment: sftp -i file.ppk user_id@server.name.com

Comment: Try giving it the full path to the key:
sftp -i /home/bob/.ssh/mykey bob@example.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30215/discussion-between-ashish-and-botteknotten).