# SSH doesn't accept my passphrase

Tags: ssh, putty

They sent me a `.ppk` key and a passphrase for their server. Pageant on Windows accepts this passphrase and opens a key. But when I try to actually connect to the server I have problems.

```
$ ssh -i '/home/foo/bar.ppk' johnappleseed@example.com
  Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/bar.ppk': 
  Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/bar.ppk': 
  Enter passphrase for key '/home/foo/bar.ppk': 
  johnappleseed@example.com's password:
```

Everytime I enter the passphrase it acts like that phrase is wrong. And then server just asks for my password. Can anybody explain a noob what is the problem in here?

Connecting with PuTTY on Windows I gets an error `our key was refused`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH key asking for passphrase on Unix but not Window](http://superuser.com/questions/986171/ssh-key-asking-for-passphrase-on-unix-but-not-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to convert my .ppk to openssh

```
sudo apt-get install putty-tools
puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O private-openssh -o id_dsa
```

Thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux) answer.